# Django: call a function after a model is saved

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

What I am trying to do is execute a function after model is saved. For eg: when I upload a db dump file through admin, i want to load it that time to db.

I tried following thing by overriding save function:

```
class DumpFile(models.Model)
 file = models.FileField(upload_to="dump")
 def save():
  super(models.Model,self).save()
  <LOAD DUMP  LOGIC>
```

Here it is giving attribute error super has no attribute save().
I don't understand what is the problem there. Please let me know this problem or about any function which works after models are saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super` is supposed to be given the current class, not the parent class:

```
super(DumpFile, self).save()
```

Also, look into [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save), which are another mechanism for making things happen after standard Django events.

Comment: Thanks a lot, signals is also a wonderful concept about which I was not knowing till now.